# Launch at startup and Mac App Store

Tags: macos, cocoa, app-store, sandbox, appstore-approval

I've read lots of articles about creating helper tools as `LSUIElement` and then have them added to LoginItems using `SMLoginItemSetEnabled`.

What I want to know is, am I allowed to add the **main** app to LoginItems instead of creating a helper? (And the main app run as a `LSUIElement` shows in the status bar.)

Since the features were all in the helper and the main app is just a launcher, due to sandbox I can't really validate the receipt within the helper, so I can't prevent people from start the helper directly.

And if it's allowed (I have seem such app but not sure how they did it, such as "[Flamingo](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/flamingo/id728181573?mt=12)"), how to add it to LoginItems without have it should down when toggle the settings? As `SMLoginItemSetEnabled` will terminate the app when pass false.

Thanks.

Comment: Your helper/main app functions sound back-to-front.  The helper should just be for launching and the functionality should be in the main app (where you can validate the receipt).

Comment: I just want to have it work like Dropbox, which has no dock icon but only in the status bar, which user can toggle show/hide dock icon and launch at startup.

Comment: But also not distributed via the app store...

Comment: I have similar requirements (but haven't implemented them yet) and articles like the following look useful.  He creates all the functionality in the main app and uses the helper just for launching: http://blog.timschroeder.net/2012/07/03/the-launch-at-login-sandbox-project/

Comment: @trojanfoe that was a smart idea! Thanks!